# Making an ISO of MBR + X amounts of partitions

Tags: dd, iso

I am trying to make an ISO of a Windows Backup disc that I "burned" to my microSD card, which I did in desperation due to lack of HDD storage at the time. Now I want to get it out of there and onto the HDD again as an ISO file, instead of a partition as it originally was.

I have tried to do what I think should be sufficient but has been doubting due to Windows telling me the ISO is corrupt. So, what I did:

First I did a lot of calculating, adding sums and whatever to get the final sector, but then I realised I can just get the sector by running fdisk and getting the end sector of the partition I want, which is 1 in this case, and add 1, to get that index since I read somewhere that it is necessary (tried without as well but it failed, hence looking it up):

```
[~]: sudo fdisk /dev/sdc
[sudo] password for simon: 

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.26.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 29.8 GiB, 32009355264 bytes, 62518272 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1e6e3d4a

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *     2048 25671679 25669632 12.2G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Command (m for help):
```

The partition starts at 2048 and ends at **25671679**, which gives me the count for dd to be **25671680**. My dd command will then be, given a sector size of **512** (also given above):

```
[img]: sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=WindowsBackupDisk.iso bs=512 count=25671680
25671680+0 records in
25671680+0 records out
13143900160 bytes (13 GB) copied, 158.92 s, 82.7 MB/s
```

Running this command should give me a file with a size of the sum of the partition and the **MBR**. If I were to have more partitions, I would have just used the end sector of the **last** one that I wanted to include, right?

I wanted to do this because I have this on a 32GB microSD card I wish to use for something else. However, when going into Windows I try to mount it in order to verify it's integrity but it does not work. Is this because Windows can't read the format of a raw ISO like this or is it because it is corrupt?

Running **file** on the ISO gives me:

```
[img]: file WindowsBackupDisk.iso 
WindowsBackupDisk.iso: DOS/MBR boot sector MS-MBR Windows 7 english at 
offset 0x163 "Invalid partition table" at offset 0x17b "Error loading 
operating system" at offset 0x19a "Missing operating system", disk 
signature 0x1e6e3d4a; partition 1 : ID=0xc, active, start-CHS 
(0x0,32,33), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 2048, 25669632 sectors
```

What can I do to make sure that it is readable in my Windows OS? I would prefer to not install MagicISO or such programs on my Windows because I thought I could do it in Linux, but if it is the only solution then I'd like to know why so I can take this as a lesson.

Mounting partition 1:

```
[img]: sudo mount -o loop,offset=1048576 -t vfat WindowsBackupDisk.iso /mnt/tmp/
[sudo] password for simon: 
[img]: ls /mnt/tmp/
boot  bootmgr  bootmgr.efi  efi  reagent.xml  sources  System Volume Information
```